# MYSQL не работает MATCH AGAINST

Tags: java, mysql, запрос, spring-jpa

Запрос:     `@Query("SELECT m FROM Message WHERE MATCH (textMessage) AGAINST (':word')")`

Ошибка: `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: AGAINST near line 1, column 63 [SELECT m FROM server.entity.Message WHERE MATCH (textMessage) AGAINST (':word')]`

Что ему не нравится в моем against?

UPD:
Исправил следующим образом:

```
@Query(
            value = "SELECT * FROM Message WHERE MATCH(textMessage) AGAINST (:word IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> getMessageByWordIndexed(@Param("word") String word);
```

Но почему то этот запрос все равно не использует индексы...
UPD2: Понял, что написал глупость по поводу индексов.

Comment: как вы себе представляете что конструкция предназначенная для работы с полнотекстовым индексом  не использует этот индекс?

Comment: Я проверил - удалил индекс - и понял, что написал бред. Но я не пойму, почему он работает с "переменным успехом". Я написал эту глупость, потому что поиск по индексам оказался в среднем дольше, чем обычный (на 100 мс), в базе из 150 строк. Я было подумал, что это от того, что нативные методы затрачивают больше ресурсов и нужна база покрупнее, наклепал еще строк (260), но разница только увеличилась. Что я упускаю?

Comment: 150 и 410 строк это не тот объем  на котором надо смотреть разницу производительности. Нативный если вы имеете в виду `like`, будет использовать индекс только в случае конструкции `like 'xxx%`, для `%xxx%` - нет и скорость сразу снизится. на 150 строках вы это не заметите. при FTS вы считай имеете %xxx% индексированный.

Comment: Я так и понял, что слишком маленький размер базы. Нативный - имею ввиду MATCH AGAINST, без nativeQuery = true он не работает. Я думал, что like работает без индекса FTS всегда...я делал два этих запроса, потому что хотел сравнить скорость.

Comment: like может использовать обычный индекс по полю если шаблон не начинается с %

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, AGAINST в запросе не работает по той же причине, что и не работает * после SELECT: в hql это не предусмотрено ([ссылка на мануал с синтаксисом HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)).

Для того, что бы этот запрос работал, надо создать нативный запрос ([на мысль меня подтолкнул это мануал](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)).